# Resigning from Tier 2 sponsorship and switching to Tier 4

Tags: uk-visa

I was in Tier 2 sponsorship visa and a university offered me PhD scholarship. I resigned from the office and the HR said that my sponsorship will also be invalidated from the last day at my work (April 27, 2018). The university sent me offer letter in first week of April (for May 2018 session) and I have applied for ATAS clearance but still haven't heard from them. The estimated decision date for ATAS is 8th May.Then once it is cleared, I will be issued CAS letter and I can apply for Tier 2. 
Do I need to go back to my counry to apply for Tier 4 visa or Can i apply from here? Will my tier 2 visa invalidates once the Certificate of Sponsorship is invalidated?

Thank you very much